# What PERL env vars need to be set for a local install?

Tags: installation, perl, environment-variables

I'm running Centos 7.2, which has Perl 5.16 by default.

Some software one of my users has requested requires at least Perl 5.18, with a preference for 5.22. I've installed 5.24 in `/opt/perl/5.24` using:

```
./Configure -des -Dprefix=/opt/perl/5.24 -Dotherlibdirs=/opt/perl/5.24/lib/perl5 -Uuseperlio
```

We use Environment Modules, and I only want this one piece of software to use this Perl version - it will otherwise be, in the jargon - "unsupported".

What environment variables now need to be set for the use of that software?

Obviously I'll append `/opt/perl/5.24/bin` to `$PATH`, but what other variables does perl need/require - for the installation of modules and etc? (using cpanimus)

I can see there is a `$PERL5LIB`, and a `$PERL_PATH` on various posts - but are these canonical for Perl or just related to the posts in question?

Comment: The Programming Perl (third edition, http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~bmg/software/Perl%20Books/prog/ch19_02.htm ) would suggest that we only need $PERL5LIB but it also looks out of date.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should need any environment variables to be set, as long as your Perl is installed correctly. Simply invoking your `perl` interpreter should be sufficient. Environment variables relevant to `perl` are documented on the [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) page of [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org), but variables such as `$PERL5LIB` are only used to *override* the normal behavior. You should not need to set them in this situation.